# How to transfer shaders?

Tags: shaders

I have downloaded a metal node setup from Chocofur.com and when I open their blend file, I can access all their nodes. However when I try to copy paste them into my file, it does not work. How can I get their node setup to mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to assign the material to an object (i.e. the default cube), then save the origin file, open the new file and choose "file - append - choose the chocofur file, object (not "mesh"), cube: the cube will be imported with all its attributes, with its material node tree.

Another is select all the nodes, Ctrl G make group, rename the group, save, open the new file and append the node group.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much....Both ways worked!!Thanks and God bless :)